# Send information about checked table view items to server

Tags: arrays, ios, uitableview, checked

I'm building an iPhone application, where I have a table view with items that can be checked on or off. When the user has checked the selected items, I have to send that information back to my server. However, I don't know the optimal way to do this. Should I load the information into an array? Maybe a dictionary? And can you give specific examples of how to do this with code?

Thanks.

No one?

**Update**

To be clear, everything regarding URL connections is taken care of. All I need is a way to sort the information in an array or the like, where the index path of the items is used to represent the checked table view cells. After that, I'll convert the information to JSON, which I will then parse on the server. I have a JSON encode/decode library, so I don't need any information on how to do that.

Comment: About how many items would be transferred?  Would you be sending an int per item or a whole set of fields per item?  What kind of server is it?  Does the server side need JSON, XML, other?  It doesn't matter what data structure is used on the device.  Before finding the "optimal" way, have you been able to transfer to the server at all using NSURLConnection or some third party library?

Comment: Updated my post with some more info.

Comment: I think if you're keeping track of a list of selected index paths, the simplest way is to have an NSMutableArray containing NSIndexPath objects.  But how will the server know what "section 1, row 3" relates to?  Perhaps you should send the unique identifiers related to your model objects that you are displaying in the table view (not what section+row they happen to display on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this seems to solve my problem. If someone knows a more elegant solution, please let me know.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 / 255 green:0.0 / 255 blue:0.0 / 255 alpha:1];
        [selectedSources removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

    } else {

        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:72.0 / 255 green:104.0 / 255 blue:152.0 / 255 alpha:1];
        [selectedSources addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

    }

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

`selectedSources` is an NSMutableArray, which I then JSON encode  and send to my server. Based on the index path, I can then identify which table view cells have been  checked/unchecked server side.

Thanks, Anna!

Comment: If this works without any issues (it's quick enough and the correct row#s get sent) then ok but instead of reading/writing directly from/to the cell, I'd only read/write the selectedSources array in this method and then call reloadRowsAtIndexPath at the end (and in cellForRowAtIndexPath it checks selectedSources and sets the accessoryType, etc appropriately).